# "The European raw materials" or "European raw materials"?

Tags: definite-articles

I am confused about the usage of "the" before *European, British*.  I am able to find situations where "the" before European, to denote the people of Europe, and the European army to denote the army of Europe. However, I was equally able to find "the" not being used before European when they are denote non-living or emotional things. Like "European raw materials". Please advise me on this!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this pair of examples shows the particularisation that the definite article confers on a noun group (and focusing attention solely on the *the*, if present, before *British*):

> British trees have to be able to withstand cold wet winters.
>
> The British trees are in the south-east part of the arboretum.

Without the *the*, we're making a general statement about those species of trees native to Britain.

When the *the* is included, it indicates that we have some particular subset of some larger set - a collection in a garden centre, or a planting in a large arboretum containing trees from many countries - in mind, and we are conveying that sense.

The British Army is a particular (though not constant) body / organisation, and so takes *the*.

'Raw materials' would usually be used in a general sense, thus without the *the*. Unless there is particularisation - pre-reference (again, focusing attention solely on the *the* before *raw materials*):

> We will be having the sand, cement and timber delivered this morning,
> and the builders will arrive after lunch. The raw materials should be
> unloaded near the site hut.

or post-reference:

> *The raw materials needed to make concrete are:*

With Europeans, unless a particular subset is being referenced, the *the* is largely optional:

> (The) Europeans do like their wine.

There is a complicating factor with British. It is not a noun (European is both adjective and noun). But it may be used as a noun (though it retains its classification as an adjective). When those adjectives that may be used this way are used this way, the *the* is usually mandatory: The rich; the poor; the lame; the British.

Comment: I'm not too bothered personally about the anonymous downvotes, but if what I consider to be a helpful and accurate answer is signalled as in some way defective - without any explanation - I feel that some other vehicle may be necessary to help genuine enquirers. A pity, because I've enjoyed contributing to and learning from this website. It is true that the question is not targeted too well, but in such a complex area (Cobuild have a 100-page monograph on articles) should one expect a precisely framed question?

Comment: This is a very good answer, and I hope you won't be offended if I say yoursecond example is confusing. It contains three *the*'s, only the third of which is relevant to your point. Using or omitting the second will change the meaning slightly, and the first is only right if there has been previous reference to these materials (normally it would be *some* or nothing at all)

Comment: No, Tim - it's the negative tag that may arise, probably from someone who has not enjoyed an opinion contrary to their own pet one in a different thread, with no explanation - signalling that an answer is unsound - that concerns me. Point taken about the example - it's hard to avoid _the_'s and still sound natural - but I was assuming that re-using the OP's noun-group choice of 'raw materials', and the indication of pre-referencing for that example, would identify the particular _the_ being considered. I've now tightened the explanations.